# How can I access a block from flask(not from template)?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

here's my generalized question:

base.html :

```
<html>
  <head>
    {% if title %}
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    {% else %}
    <title>test</title>
    {% endif %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %} {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I write a function that can directly create a block? maybe something like:

```
@app.route("/foo")
def foo():
    content = "<h1>this is foo page</h1>"
    return render_html("base.html", content = content)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to render HTML in your [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) template **without** [HTML escaping](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#html-escaping). By default, Jinja2 is configured to do automatic escaping of all variables you interpolate.

This means that

```
<h1>this is foo page</h1>
```

is actually rendered as

```
&lt;h1&gt;this is foo page&lt;/h1&gt;
```

so you don't accidentally use HTML in your pages where you didn't mean to. This is **very important** to protect against [Cross Site Scripting (XSS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks.

If you are going to bypass this automatic escaping, and deliberately insert HTML into your templates, you must make sure you know what you are doing - never allow unescaped user input to get into these variables.

With the background lesson and security warnings out of the way, if you do know what you are doing, you *can* explicitly mark values as "safe" in your template, so they will not be escaped. Just use Jinja2's builtin filter, [safe](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#safe), like so:

```
  <body>
    {{ content | safe }}
  </body>
```

In your case, I think you also wanted to have a block, so you can override with [template inheritance](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#template-inheritance). For an example of that, play with this complete example app

test.py:

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/foo")
def foo():
    content = "<h1>this is foo content</h1>"
    return flask.render_template("base.html", content=content)

@app.route("/bar")
def bar():
    content = "<h1>this is bar content</h1>"
    return flask.render_template("child.html", content=content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

templates/base.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    {% if title %}
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    {% else %}
    <title>test</title>
    {% endif %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}{{ content | safe }}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

templates/child.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  {{ super() }}
  <h2>And this bit comes from the child template</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

view :

```
@app.route("/foo")
def foo():
content = "<h1>this is foo page</h1>"
return render_template("base.html", content = content)
```

base.html:

```
<html>
<head>
{% if title %}
<title>{{title}}</title>
{% else %}
<title>test</title>
{% endif %}
</head>
<body>
{% block content %} 
{% if content %}
{{ content | safe }}
{% else %}
No content provided
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```